# How to use jQuery's inputmask in AdminLTE when included via composer

Tags: symfony, twig, composer-php, adminlte, jquery-inputmask

## Short version

How do I use `inputmask` from a `twig` inheriting from the `avanzu/AdminThemeBundle` base?

## Context

I'm using the AdminLTE admin panel template (https://adminlte.io/) in a symfony3 project.

To do so, I use the Avanzu project (https://github.com/avanzu/AdminThemeBundle) which allows me two main advantages:

- I'm able to install it via composer.
- I have pre-made twig blocks which I can just overwrite in my twigs, for reusability.

The thing is that I need an `<input>` in a form to express an amount in Euros. I wanted to use the `inputmask` which you can see in action in AdminLte here: https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html

Buen when I place this code...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Intl US phone mask:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': ['999-999-9999 [x99999]', '+099 99 99 9999[9]-9999']" data-mask="" type="text">
    </div>
<!-- /.input group -->
</div>
```

...the only thing I can see is the input box but no mask in it. Seems that the HTML works but the JS does not.

(PD: The code is a phone instead of Euros because I started copying the example to later edit it.)

## Prerequisites

I have already run the `php bin/console avanzu:admin:fetch-vendor` command and the `php bin/console assets:install --symlink` both mentioned here https://github.com/avanzu/AdminThemeBundle

I also have the assetic bundle in place and pre-loaded in the kernel.

## More context

In my page, I see that the main template is including all LTE javascripts:

```
<script src="/hello-trip/dislodge-galvanize/web/bundles/avanzuadmintheme/static/dev/scripts/admin-lte-all.js"></script>
```

Also if I explore `admin-lte-all.js` it is there and searching for `inputmask` reveals it is there in the minified version:

[image]

But still, in the page, I can see this:

[image]

While in the demo site, I can see this:

[image]

IDK what's going on or if I should do something else.

## Question

What should I code in my twig to make a `<input class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': ['999-999-9999 [x99999]', '+099 99 99 9999[9]-9999']" data-mask="" type="text">` input to work?

Comment: after `assets:install` have you tried to `cache:clear --env=prod`?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your js

```
 $('[data-mask]').inputmask()
```